# How to validate uniqueness in DB via Joi.validate?

Tags: node.js, schema, joi

Is this possible to insert a function to a Joi validation schema which will check in the DB if the value is unique?

(The check will be done by a function that I make, inside Joi function method).

Maybe something like this:

```
phone: Joi.customCheck(function(v) {
  let bool;
  // check in DB if v is already exists, then assign the value to bool...
  return bool;
}).required()
```

I have searched in Google and in the Joi api reference but found nothing.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I dont thik this is a usecase for joi. It is more about validating incomming data through an api for instance. If you are using a db lib like mongoose or sequel, you can handle db validations with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the new function `any().external()` (since version `16.0.0`). This can be used to do a database lookup.

```js
const lookup = async (id) => {

    const user = await db.get('user', id);
    if (!user) {
        throw new Error('Invalid user id');
    }
};

const schema = Joi.string().external(lookup);
await schema.validateAsync('1234abcd');
```